# mp3 -> wav с помощью Lame  c++

Tags: аудио, c++

Здравствуйте,

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, не могу сообразить как закодировать pcm в wav.
Pcm получил из mp3 с помощью Lame, код ниже. Как дальше закодировать его в wav не понимаю. Насколько я понял надо использовать функцию lame_encode_buffer, но как это сделать я не понимаю. Кто пользовался Lame можете помочь?

```
 std::ifstream mp3_file.open(fname.c_str(),std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
 hip_t decoder = hip_decode_init();
 mp3_file.seekg(0);
 std::cout << "  File size: " << flen << std::endl;

 ID3 tag(fname);
 std::cout << "  Has ID3v2 Tag: ";
 if(tag.hasTag())
     std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
 else
     std::cout << "No" << std::endl;
 std::cout << "  Tag size: " << tag.size() << std::endl;
 if(tag.hasTag())
     mp3_file.seekg(tag.size()); // Skip ID3v2 tag

 const int mp3bufsize = 4096;
 const int pcmbufsize = 4096*100;

 unsigned char mp3buf[mp3bufsize];

 std::vector<int16_t> pcm_l;
 std::vector<int16_t> pcm_r;
 int16_t pcm_l_buf[pcmbufsize];
 int16_t pcm_r_buf[pcmbufsize];

 do {
    mp3_file.read((char*)mp3buf, mp3bufsize);
    size_t numread = mp3_file.gcount();
    if(numread > 0)
    {
            int numdec = hip_decode( decoder, mp3buf, numread, pcm_l_buf, pcm_r_buf );
            if(numdec > 0)
            {

                    for(int i=0; i<numdec; i++)
                    {
                            pcm_l.push_back(pcm_l_buf[i]);
                            pcm_r.push_back(pcm_r_buf[i]);
                    }
            }
    }
 } while(!mp3_file.eof());
 hip_decode_exit(decoder);
 std::vector<int16_t> *pcm = new std::vector<int16_t>[2];
 pcm[0] = pcm_l; 
 pcm[1] = pcm_r;
```

Comment: PCM(ИКМ) - это уже wav, после него просто нечего декодировать, его надо просто записать в RIFF-файл.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я понял чего мне не хватало - заголовка WAV, добавил заголовок и все стало отлично ;)